# How to select just a row of table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have created a table on my application same following code

```
<table class="spreadsheet">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I select a row by click with following jQuery code

```
 $("tr").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("otherstyle");
}
```

and my css is

```
tr.otherstyle td
{
    background-color: #d1db3e;
    color:#000;
}
```

I would like when I click on a row, other rows be **unselected**,
and just one row be selected.

How we could create this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("table.spreadsheet tr").click(function(){
    $("table.spreadsheet tr").removeClass("otherstyle");
    $(this).toggleClass("otherstyle");
});
```

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/oveba)**

Answer (score 5):

```
$("tr").click(function(){

 $('tr').removeClass("otherstyle");
 $(this).toggleClass("otherstyle");

}
```

or

```
$("tr").click(function(){     

 $(this).toggleClass("otherstyle").siblings().removeClass("otherstyle");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For sake of performance, I'd change rahul's answer to

```
$("table.spreadsheet tr").click(function(){
    $("table.spreadsheet tr").removeClass("otherstyle");
    $(this).addClass("otherstyle"); // avoid checking if it has the class "otherstyle"
                                      // because it does not
});
```

Not that'd be a real kill, but hey, shouldn't we always write fast/optimized code?